# Array to String Conversion error in CodeIgniter?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, foreach

This is the code

My Controller file

```
public function view_resume($id)
{
    $this->load->model('ORB_Model');

    $data['get_masterData'] = $this->ORB_Model->get_masterData($id);
}
```

My Model file:

```
public function get_educationData($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('edu_tb',['edu_id'=>$id],2)->result_array();
    }
```

My View File:

```
<?php
     print_r($get_educationData);
die;
// output array()
foreach ($get_educationData as $key){
?>
 value="<?php echo $key->['edu_name']; ?>"
 <?php
} 
?>
```

Now when i print_r my $get_educationData it will give empty array() only.
my data is not coming from model.
in my view file nothing shown there.

Comment: show how you are passing data in view in controller

Comment: do this `print_r($get_masterData);` instead of  `print_r($get_educationData);`

Comment: print_r($get_masterData); is working bcz i return only single row

Comment: but in get_educationData i want to get multiple data present in single master_id, thats why i use the foreachloop.

Comment: that is why  i ask you to show how you are passing data in view in controller pls show so that some help can get from there

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be like this :

*You have to call `get_educationData` method also in your controller like this :*

```
public function view_resume($id)
{
    $this->load->model('ORB_Model');

    $data['get_masterData'] = $this->ORB_Model->get_masterData($id);
    $data['get_educationData'] = $this->ORB_Model->get_educationData($id);

    /* load view here like this */
    $this->load->view('your_view' ,$data);
}
```

Your model `get_educationData`  should be like this :

```
public function get_educationData($id)
{
    if ( ! empty($id))
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('edu_tb', array('edu_id' => $id));
    }
    else
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('edu_tb');
    }

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

Your view should be like this :

*Instead of object notation use array since your return data is in array form*

```
<?php
//print_r($get_masterData);
//print_r($get_educationData);
if ( ! empty($get_educationData))
{
   foreach ($get_educationData as $item)
   {
      echo $item['edu_name'];
   } 
}
?>
```

Comment: I have used this in my code                                                                    $data['get_educationData'] = $this->ORB_Model->get_educationData($id);                     and view is as it as u send but when i print_r($get_educationData) is print only array() like thi

Comment: make sure your `edu_tb` table has data with corresponding `edu_id`

Comment: it has the data i inserted multiple times to test.

Comment: i have updated your model method  `get_educationData` pls check my updated answer , hope this will help you

Comment: print_r($get_educationData) shows nothing, var_dump is giving o/p NULL and on runtime error invalid argument for foreach

Comment: have u implement model method `get_educationData`  as given in my answer

Comment: and the error you get is just because you have no data return from your table make sure `edu_id`  column name for id is correct

Comment: the id name,table name,method name, model name, master id name i have checked but return null and give error of invalid argument for foreach.

Comment: is there any column `edu_id`, either you passing wrong variable in your view or your view is different , show your controller with view file